# Getting/Fetching Datas that is Queried on Datasource of Kendo DropdownList and use it on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, kendo-ui

Can I ask on what is the way of Getting the Values inside the Datasource that is queried and use it , because on my Json result there is column for Latitude and Longitude and i want to use it to make the map center onchange of dropdown of location

**This is my Dropdown List for Location**

```
        $("#ddlLocation").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Address",
            dataValueField: "Client_CustomerID",
            autoBind: false,
            optionLabel: "-- Please Select Position --",
            template: '<h5>${ data.Address }</h5>',
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Dashboard/LoadCompanyDropdownList?userId=' + userId,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST"
                    }
                }
            }          
        });

        $("#LocationInputs").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Address",
            dataValueField: "Client_CustomerID",  
            //                    index: 0,
            autoBind: false,
            change: function () {
                var value = this.value();
                if (value) {


**This is where i want to use the fetched Latitude and Longitude**


                }
                else {
                    $("#PositionGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
                } 
            },
            cascadeFrom: "PositionInputs",
            optionLabel: "-- Please Select Position --",
            template: '<h5>${ data.Address }</h5>',
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Dashboard/LoadCompanyDropdownList?userId=' + userId,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**This is LoadCompanyDropdownList**

```
 public JsonResult LoadCustomerList()
    {


        // check if search string has value
        // retrieve list of workers filtered by search criteria
        var list = (from a in db.Client_Customer_Location
                    join b in db.Client_Customer
                        on a.Client_CustomerID equals b.ID
                    where a.LogicalDelete == false
                          && b.LogicalDelete == false
                            && a.Longitude != null
                             && a.Longitude != 0

                    select new
                    {
                        b.ID,
                        a.Client_CustomerID,
                        a.Address_Line1,
                        a.Address_Line2,
                        a.City,
                        a.STATE_LookID,
                        a.ZipCode,
                        a.Latitude,
                        a.Longitude,
                        a.LogicalDelete,
                    }).ToList();

        List<CustomerInfo> clist = new List<CustomerInfo>();
        foreach (var row in list)
        {
            CustomerInfo ci = new CustomerInfo
            {
                ID = row.ID,
                Client_CustomerID = row.Client_CustomerID,
                ClientID = row.ClientID,
                AddressLine1 = row.Address_Line1 + " " + row.Address_Line2 + " " + row.City + " " + GetLookupDisplayValById(row.STATE_LookID),

                Latitude = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Latitude), 8),
                Longitude = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Longitude), 8),
                LogicalDelete = row.LogicalDelete

            };
            clist.Add(ci);
        }

        return Json(clist.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.AddressLine1), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
change: function () {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
    var lat = dataItem.Latitude;
    var long = dataItem.Longitude;

    var value = this.value();
        if (value) {
              ........
        }
```